# How to apply Ramer-Douglas-Peucker to an image?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I read a research paper about triangular sign detection that used `canny edge detection` and then applied `Ramer-Douglas-Peucker` to detect the triangle shaped sign from an image, like in the below photo.

[image: Triangular sign photo]

I managed to apply `canny edge detection` for my image, but i am super confused how to apply `Ramer-Douglas-Peucker` to get output results like in the above photo.

[image: My image]

Comment: Douglas Peucker is a method for contour approximation that minimizes the error between the approximate and original contour. You can apply DP with the OpenCV function ‘approxPolyDP’. You should find the right approximation parameter (essentially the error you accept, it should be fairly significant) and look for a contour that has exactly 3 vertices - a triangle. Also, the Canny parameters also should be tweaked to reduce noise, or you may try a bracketed search with multiple values and find triangles in the multiple Canny outputs.

Answer (score 1):

The [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) can be used for line simplification. Meaning it makes lines which are almost straight, straight. Have a look at

> The Douglas-Peucker algorithm for line simplification: Re-evaluation through visualization

if you want to understand it.

So the algorithm helps you by removing noise. It's nothing specific about triangles, except that they have straight lines.