# Get Peaks in Plot Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following data:

```
data = np.array([ 0.,  0.,  0., 94., 30., 30., 30., 31., 29., 30., 29., 28., 26.,
       29., 28., 29., 31., 32., 31., 29., 31., 31., 30., 34., 28., 31.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 54.,  9.,  9.,  7.,  7.,
       14., 18., 13.,  8.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.])
```

If I plot it, it looks, like that:

[image]

Now, I would like to automatically identify the points in red. **Any idea how I can do that?**

**EDIT:**
Tried `scipy.signal`, but it is not detecting the peaks correctly, at least with the default configuration:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(data, height=20)
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot(peaks, data[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How are these points considered as peaks.? Is it like above some threshold.? Like points above value 35 is a peak.?

Comment: @SreeramTP Thanks for your question. I consider as peaks, all points for which there is a considerable difference between either the right or left neighboring point.

Comment: Why are the other peaks wrong?

Comment: @MartinThoma I consider as peaks, all points for which there is a considerable difference between either the right or left neighboring point.

Comment: So then you have your algorithm, I guess. This is similar what Douglas-Peucker does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scipy.signal` works (at least most times), if you give it the right smoothing. You can also use wavelet transform (`find_peaks_cwt`) which smoothenes using a wavelet and thus works slightly better than `find_peaks` for noisy data

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks_cwt
peaks = find_peaks_cwt(data, widths=np.ones(data.shape)*2)-1
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot(peaks, data[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is the Douglas-Peucker algorithm, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49377181/562769

The idea is to simplify that line until you are only left with the most relevant points. Then you take every point above a threshold (e.g. above mean) and you have the peaks.

I vaguely remember that scipy signal processing has a more sophisticated approach

Comment: `scipy.signal` got a `find_peaks` function

Comment: @SreeramTP Please have a look at my updated question